# How to start doing TDD in a django project?

Tags: django, tdd

I have read a lot of essays talking about benifits TDD can bring to a project, but I have never practiced TDD in my own project before.

Now I'm starting an experimental project with Django, and I think maybe I can have a try of TDD.

But what I find now is that I don't even know how to answer the question "what should I put in my test cases?".

Please tell me how should I plan TDD in a project, in this case, a web project based on Django.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your first step should be to read over the django test documentation...

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#topics-testing

After that your first test should be as simple as

- Create a test client
- Issue a request for your *intended* main page
- check the return status code is 200

now run your test, and watch it fail because you don't have a main page yet.

Now, work on getting that test to pass and repeat the process.

Answer (score 37):

I've started writing a tutorial on the topic. It covers pretty much all the steps in the official Django tutorial, and it includes full browser-automation testing with Selenium, so you can test javascript too...

http://tdd-django-tutorial.com/

(sources at https://github.com/hjwp/Test-Driven-Django-Tutorial)

[edit 2013-04-15]  I'm now writing a book for O'Reilly on the topic.  IMO it presents things in a much better way that my old tutorial. Check it out at

http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/

(it's still free if you want it to be!)

Comment: This TDD Django tutorial is brilliant. I've seen hwjp present it in a workshop, and it is dense with content and good ideas.

Comment: fully updated for Django 1.4!

Comment: Your website is down, 500 internal server error. Just wanted to help you in case you didnt notice.

Comment: Your site is down again. Looking forward to checking it out once it's back up.

Comment: up again!  thx Ghopper21

Comment: Thanks for the great book. I just started reading it, and it's amazing.